# Read the json and store the key as bash variables

Tags: json, bash, shell

I am trying to read the json file and store the keys as bash variable and the values as variable value. For instance here is my test.json:

```
{
"Day":'0',
"num":'85',
"Qtr":"[20183, 20184, 20191, 20192]",
"pSize":"75"
}
```

I need to store the variables like this in a bash file:

```
    $Day=0
    $num=85
    $Qtr=[20183, 20184, 20191, 20192]
    $psize=75
```

I found a way to extract the value using jq, but I am unable to store the key as variable in bash

```
-bash-4.2$ Qtr=`jq .Qtr test.json`
-bash-4.2$ echo $Qtr
"[20183, 20184, 20191, 20192]"
```

Could someone please provide a snippet as to how to loop through a json file and store the key as variables and values as values?

Thank you in advance

Comment: did you try export Qtr=`jq .Qtr test.json`?

Comment: Thanks. Yes as you can see my post,  I 've already tried that. The main issue is how do I store the key as a variable in bash?

Comment: What do you mean store? WHat exactly are you trying to do? Aren't you echo-ing a stored value?

Comment: Well there are some errors in your JSON above. 1: You should not be using single quotes `'` and 2: That thing that looks like an array is not because it is actually a string (it has quotes around it).

Comment: Once you fix the string issue: `Qtr =( $(jq .Qtr[] test.json) )`

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I just want to parse the json and store the key as bash variables like this: $Day=0
              $num=85

Comment: @MartinYork please ignore the array, I want to extract the entire array as string into a bash variable, that's it

Answer (score 1):

Would you please try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS== read key value; do
    printf -v "$key" "$value"
done < <(jq -r 'to_entries|map("\(.key)=\(.value|tostring)")|.[]' test.json)

# test of the variables
echo "Day: $day"
echo "Qtr: $Qtr"
echo "num: $num"
echo "pSize: $pSize"
```

- The `jq` command `jq -r 'to_entries|map("\(.key)=\(.value|tostring)")|.[]' test.json` converts the json object into `key=value` pairs.
- The output of `jq` is fed to the `while` loop via the process substitution
  `<(command)`.
- The `-v varname` option to the `printf` command assigns the variable
  indirecly expressed with `varname` to the output.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. it worked like a charm. Thanks a ton for showing this code snippet and I really appreciate the explanation as well.